# Visual studio use lf line endings like open source repositories

Tags: git, visual-studio-2017

I have cloned a few open source libraries e.g. rosyln and fsharp and can see all files have line endings lf.

As these use visual studio as ide, I am woundering how this is achieved by the people working on these when new file is created in ide as default is crlf.

.gitattributes is text auto, so I would have thought when cloned and opened in Windows files would have eol of crlf but they are lf.

Don't understand how this is achieved but looking to achieve same(lf local and pushed to repository database as lf)

Answer (score 0):

I did not clone, I downloaded the zip which is LF.
If I had cloned it would be CRLF

So just need .gitattributes file with text auto and git will do the right thing